# Docker Container with Wiremock does not refresh changes from volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I have created this `Dockerfile` and copied it into **/my/project/wiremock** directory, based on the samples from https://github.com/rodolpheche/wiremock-docker:

```
    FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

    ENV WIREMOCK_VERSION 2.27.1

    RUN apk add --update openssl

    # fix "No Server ALPNProcessors" when using https
    RUN apk add --update libc6-compat
    RUN ln -s /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

    # grab su-exec for easy step-down from root
    # and bash
    RUN apk add --no-cache 'su-exec>=0.2' bash

    # grab wiremock standalone jar
    RUN mkdir -p /var/wiremock/lib/ \
      && wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock-jre8- 
    standalone/$WIREMOCK_VERSION/wiremock-jre8-standalone-$WIREMOCK_VERSION.jar \
    -O /var/wiremock/lib/wiremock-jre8-standalone.jar

    WORKDIR /home/wiremock

    EXPOSE 7070 7443

    CMD java $JAVA_OPTS -cp /var/wiremock/lib/*:/var/wiremock/extensions/* 
    com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.WireMockServerRunner
```

Then I created the following `docker-compose.yml` file inside **/my/project/** directory

```
    version: '3'

    services:
      wiremock:
        image: rodolpheche/wiremock:latest
        container_name: miplata-wiremock-local
        build: ./wiremock/.
        ports:
          - "7070:8080"
          - "7443:8443"
        volumes:
          - ./wiremock/stubs:/home/wiremock
```

Children directories inside **/my/project/wiremock/stubs** are **mappings** and **__files**.

When I execute `docker-compose up`, the docker container works and I can make some requests that work fine. But my issue is, that changes inside the **stubs** directory are not refreshed automatically and then I need to restart the container every time that I create a new wiremock stub or update an existing one.

Do you have any idea if I am doing something wrong? It would be nice to continue working without restarting the container.

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My recommedation is to store both mappings and response bodies in files.

By default:

1. Mapping files should be included in `mappings` folder
2. Body files should be included in `__files` folder.

As per my knowledge the wiremock standalone java process does the followings (regardless if it runs on the host or in a container):

1. automatically loads the latest changes in the response bodies files (from __files folder)
2. requires a `POST` call to `__admin/mappings/reset` in order to reload the mappings. For the example in the question description the cURL command looks
   like `curl -X POST http://localhost:7070/__admin/mappings/reset`

Please see below both the mapping and the reponse body files:

- mappings/hello.json

```json
{
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/hello"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "bodyFileName": "hello.json"
  }
}
```

- __files/hello.json

```json
{
  "message": "Hello World !"
}
```

For me all this works like a charm. Wiremock is an amazing pieace of software very useful for testing endpoints with stubs for different use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Changes to the contents of the stubs directory are not real-time refreshed in the WireMock application. It is possible to use the Swagger UI: http://localhost:8080/__admin/swagger-ui to reset it manually or the corresponding API call to automate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the path that contains the json files should be mapped to `/home/wiremock/mappings` inside docker instance.

```yaml
    version: '3'

    services:
      wiremock:
        image: rodolpheche/wiremock:latest
        container_name: miplata-wiremock-local
        build: ./wiremock/.
        ports:
          - "7070:8080"
          - "7443:8443"
        volumes:
          - /path/to/json_files:/home/wiremock/mappings
```

If you are running as a docker instance then the command should look like this:

```sh
# json mapping files
# mappings-checkin-mode.json mappings-kiosk-mode.json
docker run -it --rm -v $PWD:/home/wiremock/mappings -p 5050:8080 --name wiremock wiremock/wiremock:2.32.0 --enable-stub-cors
```

Comment: I have similar issue , I posted my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70961765/docker-container-with-wiremock-could-not-find-stub-mappings