# Wiremock container does not reflect mappings changes without restarting

Tags: docker, docker-compose, wiremock

I have a wiremock container with mappings and __files directory.
The __files directory is empty and my mappings directory have a json file named abc.json .

Now for running different test cases I have to update this json file multiple times and each time I have to restart the wiremock container after copying different versions of abc.json to this mappings directory.

I get the expected test results but the problem is it takes additional time as the restart of the wiremock container is involved. So any way I can achieve this without restarting the wiremock containers. I already referred to "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63532189/docker-container-with-wiremock-does-not-refresh-changes-from-volume" but that was of not much help.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. We just have to Post the request to __admin/mappings .