# Docker Container with Wiremock could not find stub mappings

Tags: docker, dockerfile, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

Link to the Repo:https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock-docker

I'm getting an error when I try to access stubs, not sure if I'm missing anything here. Can I know if the below command is correct ?

```
docker run --rm -d -p 8080:8080 -p 8443:8443 --name wiremock_demo \
  -v $PWD:/home/wiremock \
  rodolpheche/wiremock:2.25.1
```

[image]

**ERROR:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: docker run -it --rm \
  -p 8090:8080 \
  -v $PWD/samples/hello/stubs:/home/wiremock \
  wiremock/wiremock. What would be an appropriate command to run multiple test samples in directory , like I have hello directory, and random directory inside samples folder ?.                                         I tried something like this but it didn't work                                                   
 docker run -it --rm \
  -p 8090:8080 \
  -v $PWD/samples:/home/wiremock/mappings \
  wiremock/wiremock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapping should be made to `$PWD:/home/wiremock/mappings` where `PWD` has the json files.

Also json files should look like this:

```json
{
  "mappings": [
    {
      "id": "679dd3ce-55e5-45ee-b270-01dcf1b371ca",
      "request": {
        "urlPattern": "^/hello",
        "method": "GET"
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "jsonBody": {
          "status": "success",
          "message": "Hello"
        },
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        }
      },
      "uuid": "679dd3ce-55e5-45ee-b270-01dcf1b371ca"
    },
    {
      "id": "679dd3ce-55e5-45ee-b270-01dcf1b371c2",
      "request": {
        "urlPattern": "^/hello-2",
        "method": "GET"
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "jsonBody": {
          "status": "success",
          "message": "Hello-2"
        },
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        }
      },
      "uuid": "679dd3ce-55e5-45ee-b270-01dcf1b371c2"
    }
  ]
}
```

if you are running it json request object then the mapping should provide the `mappings` and the `__files` so need to map the containing folder:

```sh
docker run -it --rm \
  -p 8090:8080 \
  -v $PWD/samples/hello/stubs:/home/wiremock \
  wiremock/wiremock
```

[image]

Comment: getting this error : Exception in thread "main" com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.MappingFileException: Error loading file /home/wiremock/./mappings/samples/hello/stubs/__files/hello.json:

Comment: I have directory structure as this https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock-docker

Comment: what is your command to run docker

Comment: I ran these commands, STEP#1: git clone https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock-docker.git 
                                                                                                                             
STEP#2:                                                                                                                             docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 -p 8443:8443 --name wiremock_demo \ 
  -v $PWD:/home/wiremock/mappings \
  rodolpheche/wiremock:2.25.1

Comment: still path is not correct. If you want to run request objects instead of mappings then you should give path correctly in the sample. So just cd to the project and give command in the updated answer

Comment: you  can use what you want but you should give path correctly. The sample uses the request objects so it gives the containing path `wiremock` but  mappings jsons should be `wiremock/mappings`